# Problema Foreign Key , referencia a tabla no valida

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo una base de datos en los cuales en tres tablas hay foreign key entre ellas y me da error de hacer referencia a tabla no valida, Supongo que es porque la tabla a la que se hace referencia está mas abajo y cuando ejecuto la base de datos no la encuentra. Ponga la setencia de creacion de tabla arriba de una u otra me dan el mismo error.Hay alguna solucion que no sea añadir la foreign key despues de crear la base de datos? Esta es la unica que yo le encuentro. Gracias de antemano!

```
create table Empleado(
Codemp          int,
Num_ss          char(11)    not null,
Dni             char(9)     not null,
Nombre          varchar(50) not null,
Apellidos       varchar(100)not null,
Direccion       varchar(200),
Coddep          int,
Fecini          date,
Codcat          int,
Codemp_res      int,

Constraint PK_Empleado Primary key (Codemp),
Foreign key (Coddep) references Departamento(Coddep),
Foreign key (Fecini,Codcat) references Contrato (Fecini,Codcat)
);

create table Departamento(
Coddep      int,
Codemp_dir  int,
Nombre      varchar(100),

Constraint PK_Departamento Primary key (Coddep),
Foreign key (Codemp_dir) references Empleado(Codemp)
);

create table Contrato(
Fecini      date,
Codemp      int,
Fecfin      date,
Codcat      int     not null,

Constraint PK_Contrato Primary key(Fecini,Codemp),
Foreign key (Codemp) references Empleado (Codemp)
);
```

Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Line 15
La clave externa 'FK__Empleado__Coddep__267ABA7A' hace referencia a la tabla no válida 'Departamento'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
No se pudo crear la restricción o el índice. Vea los errores anteriores.
Este es el mensaje que muestra.

Comment: algo esta mal ahi.. por eso enes el problema.. porque hay una referencia circular entre empleado y departamento?? no deberiaeexistir relacion de departamento a empleado

Comment: acabo de dejar ahi una imagen que muestra el entidad relacion de esa base de datos, no tendria que ser asi tal y como propuse yo?

Comment: entendiste mal como leer el der.. en contrato tenes el mismo problema

Comment: el fallo de contrato ya lo entiendo, pero el de departamento no, reflejarlo en la base de datos ya que hay una dos relaciones. Como seria esta ultima?

Comment: departamento no va contra empleado.. el que sabe a que departamento pertenece es el empleado.. segun tu relacion, como conectas muchos empleados a un departamento?

Comment: pero quien sabe que empleado lo dirige es departamento no? Muchas gracias por las explicaciones y la paciencia!!

Comment: como escribiste tu relacion en la db, es 1 a 1.. no 1 a muchos.. pensalo ;)

Comment: tal y como lo veo yo, empleado necesita el codigo de departamento para saber a cual pertenece ( si esta en departamento habria demasiados codigos) y departamento tendria que tener el codigo del empleado que lo dirige ya que si estuviese en empleado habria muchos nulos

Comment: No se si el sentido de tu pregunta es otro, pero lo que veo es que estas intentando crear las tablas junto con los FK haciendo referencia a tablas que aun no existe, fijate que el error que te muestras es creando justamente el primer FK. Ese es tu problema?

Comment: es que para mi gusto, la relacion empleado-departamento deberia estar en otra tabla.. ya qu ensucia el modelo... pero bueno.. podria estar ahi, y en ese caso tenes que crear la fk despues de crear todo.

Comment: Si, pero lo que quiero saber es como solucionarlo, por que ya se que el problema es que referencio una tabla no creada aun pero no se como hacer la relacion si no es asi. Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente el error que te da el manejador es al momento de crear la primera FK haciendo referencia a una tabla que aun no existe. Debes primero crear cada una de las tablas con su llave primaria y luego puedes agregar los FK con ALTER TABLE. De esta forma puedes agregan tus llaves foraneas posterior a la creacion de las tablas:

```
ALTER table Empleado
add constraint Empleado_Coddep_FK FOREIGN KEY (Coddep) references
Departamento(Coddep);

ALTER table Empleado
add constraint Empleado_Fecini_FK FOREIGN KEY (Fecini,Codcat) references
Contrato(Fecini,Codcat);

ALTER table Departamento
add constraint Departamento_Codemp_dir_FK FOREIGN KEY (Codemp_dir) references
Empleado(Codemp);

ALTER table Contrato
add constraint Contrato_Codemp_dir_FK FOREIGN KEY (Codemp) references
Empleado(Codemp);
```